# How to create array from multiple array objects in single array object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hope you all are doing well , currently i am stuck in an issue tried with possible ways found to generate a suitable array object combination which is feasible for my csv download.

I am having an array of type:-

```
[Array(4),Array(10),Array(2),Array(15),..]
```

Expanding it shows like these:-

```
var arr= [

[{life_events: "Started studying at Escola Universitària Formatic Barcelona"}, {life_events: "Got a Pet"}, {life_events: "Travelled"}],
[{bio: "No additional details to show"}],
[{places_relationship: ""}],
[{contact_info: "Birthday6 May 1995"}, {contact_info: "No contact info to show"}],
[{places_living: "Barcelona, Spain"}],
[{overviewsection: "Works at En Mi Casa"}],
[{overviewsection: "Studies Dirección Formatic Barcelona"}]]
```

Expected output from above array objects:-

```
 [
{life_events: "Started studying at Escola Universitària Formatic Barcelona",bio: "No additional details to show",places_relationship: "", contact_info: "Birthday6 May 1995", places_living: "Barcelona, Spain", overviewsection: "Works at En Mi Casa",overviewsection: "Studies Dirección Formatic Barcelona"},
{life_events: "Got a Pet",bio: "No additional details to show",places_relationship: "", contact_info: "No contact info to show", places_living: "Barcelona, Spain", overviewsection: "Works at En Mi Casa",overviewsection: "Studies Dirección Formatic Barcelona"}
]
```

Please let me know which can be the best solution to get this kind of outcome from the above array shown.

Please consider this as an example to understand my query:-

Yeah sure please check the below:- Considering the input example:-

```
[ { a : 1 },{ a : 2 } ] [ { b : 1 } , { b : 2 } ] [ { c : 1 },{ c : 2 } ]
```

The output should be like:- `[ {a:1 , b:1 , c:1}, {a:2, b:2, c:2} ]

I am sharing my code too please check that :-

```
function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {  
        var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;
        data = args.data || null;

        if (data == null || !data.length) {
            return null;
        }

        columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
        lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

        keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

        result = '';
        result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
        result += lineDelimiter;

        data.forEach(function(item) {
            ctr = 0;
            keys.forEach(function(key) {
                if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

                result += item[key];
                ctr++;
            });
            result += lineDelimiter;
        });
        return result;
    }   

    function downloadCSV(args, stockData) {  
        var data, filename, link;
        var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
            data: stockData
        });
        if (csv == null) return;

        filename = args.filename || 'data.csv';
        if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
            csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
        }
        jQuery.trim(csv);
        data = encodeURI(csv);

        link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', data);
        link.setAttribute('download', filename);
        link.click();
    }

    function merge_data(){
        var my_main_arry = [];
        chrome.storage.local.get('overviewsection_data', function(data) {
            var data = data.overviewsection_data;
            console.log('i am here', data); // here the data contains that array.
            var opts = {};

            $(data).each(function(key,value){
                $(value).each(function(i,val){
                    $.extend(opts,val); // i tried to fix by using this but its not working as expected
                    my_main_arry.push(opts);
                })
            })
            console.log('my main array', my_main_arry);
            downloadCSV('data.csv', my_main_arry);
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please give a simple example. I couldn't get it and tell us what have you tried. And also notice `overviewsection` occurs twice in the output result

Comment: 5 and 6 should also be an array in that case

Comment: That is also an array its just i have placed it in expanded form.

Comment: So basically what you want is, if there are more than 1 object in the child array, it should append in a new object?

Comment: Can you provide a valid input and output and a clear problem statement on how to arrive at the output? The actual array without the indexes or `(10)`. Because I'm unable to tell whether `5: {overviewsection: "Works at En Mi Casa"}` is an array or not

Comment: Yeah sure please check the below:- Considering the input example:- [ { a : 1 },{ a : 2 } ] [ { b : 1 } , { b : 2 } ] [ { c : 1 },{ c : 2 } ] The output should be like:- [ {a:1 , b:1 , c:1}, {a:2, b:2, c:2} ]

Comment: Please add it in the question, preferably a snippet

Comment: In the expected output, why have you not added `{life_events: "Travelled"}` in the array? What `contact_info` should be taken in the third object of the output? If an index doesn't exist, should we take the last value from each array?

Comment: No the third output will remain empty ie., {life_events: "Travelled",bio: "",places_relationship: "", contact_info: "", places_living: "", overviewsection: "",overviewsection: ""}

Comment: what happened to `{life_events: "Travelled"}` seems to have just disappeared.

Comment: It was just an example bro.. That will come at the end consider this example i have to place it in my csv the headers will code as the key of every section and rest othe values will be comming below them showing you the complete code too.

Comment: Your input and output should be minimal and complete. Otherwise I post an answer and you say it's not the requirement. (Also, you need to @ people when you're replying. Like this @adiga. Otherwise ther wo;nt be a notification)

Comment: Let's consider `[Array(4),Array(10),Array(2),Array(15)]` how many items should be there in the output? `4` or `15`?

Comment: Consider that as it every array element will be comming as next column in csv.. you will get what kind of structure it will get .. data will get printed in csv taking key as header and next other elements as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My naive solution would be:

```js
var initialArray = [
  [ { a : 1 }, { a : 2 }, { a : 3 } ],
  [ { b : 1 }, { b : 2 } ],
  [ { c : 1 },{ c : 2 } ]
];


function sortArray(arr) {
  var maxEntries = 0; // Num of arrays you will have at the end
  var baseObj = {}; // baseObj will be = { a: '', b: '', c: '' }
  
  arr.forEach(function(collection) {
    if(collection.length > maxEntries) maxEntries = collection.length;
    var currentKey = Object.keys(collection[0])[0]; // Get the key name to store it in baseObj
    baseObj[currentKey] = ''; // Default value
  });

  var newArray = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < maxEntries; i++) {
    newArray.push(Object.create(baseObj)); // Shallow copy of baseObj
    
    arr.forEach(function(collection) {
      if(collection[i]) {
        newArray[i] = Object.assign(newArray[i], collection[i]); // Replace with the value
      }
    });
  }
  
  return newArray;
}

console.log("Result :", sortArray(initialArray));
```

You will get : `[ {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}, {a: 2, b: 2, c: 2}, {a: 3, b: '', c: ''} ]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. You can do something like this using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```js
const input = [
  [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }],
  [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }],
  [{ c: 1 }, { c: 2 }]
]

const maxLength = Math.max(...input.map(a => a.length))

const output = 
    Array.from({length: maxLength},
               (_, i) => ({ ...input.reduce((r, a, i1) => ({ ...r, ...a[i] }), {}) }))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for this too.

Answer (score 0):

**STEPS:**

1. Create an array to store the result.
2. Iterate for each `life_events` you have.
3. Construct an object with each property from other array using the index in each iteration.
4. Push the object into the result array.

Comment: holydragon can you please show me an example to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    
  var arr = [
      [ {"a": 1},{"d": 2} ],
      [ {"c": 3}]
    ]
    
    var combinedArr = arr.reduce((acc, element) => (acc.push(...element), acc), [])
    console.log(combinedArr)
```

Comment: Hey this is not what i want please check the out put array of mine.                                                        Considering the input example:- [{a:1},{a:2}][{'b:1'},{b:2}][{c:1},{c:2}] The output should be like:- [ {a:1 , b:1 , c:1}, {a:2, b:2, c:2} ]