# How to create multiple array from single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have a situation where I get the data in an array and I have to convert that to multiple arrays... Like Matrix.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

the output should be:

```
[[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[6,8],[9]]
```

this is what I have so far:

```
let i = 0;
const add = [];
while (i < list.length) {
  add.push([list[i], list[i + 2]]);
  i = i + 1;
}
return add;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create array from multiple array objects in single array object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528524/how-to-create-array-from-multiple-array-objects-in-single-array-object)

Comment: no, they have multiple arrays and they are putting in one array. Mine is the opposite.

Comment: @jakasJakas, post an answer. check if it works for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this one?

```js
let i = 0;
const list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
const add = [];
let newarr =[]
while (i < list.length) {
  add.push([list[i], list[i + 2]]);
  add.push([list[i+1],list[i+3]])
  i +=4;
}
//remove undefined item from the array
newarr = add.map(arr=>arr.filter(item =>item != undefined)).filter(item=>item!="")


console.log(newarr)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be able to solve your problem.

```
    function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
    let newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
        newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
    }
    console.log(newArr)
    return newArr;
}
chunkArrayInGroups([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],2)
```

This will divide our larger array into chunk array of  size 2 less than 2.

Comment: Your code returns in sequence order. If you check my question I need in this format: [[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[6,8],[9]]

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const visitedIndex = [];
const newArray = [];
array.forEach((element, i) => {
  if (!visitedIndex.includes(i)) {
    if (array[i+2]) {
      newArray.push([array[i], array[i+2]])
    } else {
      newArray.push([array[i]])
    }
    visitedIndex.push(i);
    visitedIndex.push(i+2);
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lodash** [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk) if you don't mind.

Or you can use recursive approach in vanila js.

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

const chunk = (arr, n) => arr.length ? [arr.slice(0, n), ...chunk(arr.slice(n), n)] : [];

console.log(chunk(array, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Your code returns in sequence order. If you check my question I need in this format: [[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[6,8],[9]]